# API and database calls on same page

Tags: php, mysql, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a PHP form on page A.

I submit that form to page B, where the info goes into the database.

I also need to make an API call to add the submitted email address to MailChimp.

I'm using this mailchimp-api script: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

The form that enters the data works by itself, and the API that adds the email works by itself.

But when I try to do both on the same page, I get:

```
This page isn’t working
XYZ.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

The relevant code is below. I've tried switching the order of the calls (API and database). And I tried putting the API call inside the conditional statement:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { }
```

Here is the whole code block:

```
    <?php

// API call

include('MailChimp.php');

use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us1');

$list_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$email = $_POST['email'];

$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => $email,
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
                'interests'    => ['xxxxxxxxxxx' => true],
            ]);

// database call

if(isset($_POST['addauth'])){

$email = $_POST['email'];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx", 3306);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$implanted = $_POST['implanted'];
$pacemaker = $_POST['pacemaker'];
$over_21 = $_POST['over_21'];
$updates = $_POST['updates'];

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO patients (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, IMPLANTED, PACEMAKER, OVER_21, UPDATES, DATE) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', CURDATE())",
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$first_name),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$last_name),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$implanted),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$pacemaker),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$over_21),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$updates));


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {          
    //echo "New record created successfully" . $sql;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

} ?>
```

Comment: Does any data get entered in the DB?

Comment: Any time you get a 500 error you need to look in your web server's error log and find the actual message.  Someone here might be able to spot your typo for you and fix this error, but in the long run you need to find the actual message which will give you a better hint and likely a line number for the error.  Look in your apache/nginx/lighttpd error log and post the error message that caused the 500 error.

Comment: Code looks "good" (no parse errors). Do you get any output if you add error_reporting(E_ALL) to your page? But like @mikeb said, check your server logs to get more info why the page returned 500.

Comment: To: vivek_23 yes the data gets added To:Bert Maurau I added error_reporting(E_ALL)  thanks for reminding me @mikeb looking in the error log I found "Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)" After searching that error, I moved the "use ..." line immediately below the include it refers to, and the page worked! Not sure why a blank line there made a difference, but it did. Thanks all!